# Linux - encrypt file system

Tags: linux, filesystems, encryption

How do I encrypt file system on Linux (/).
I know, how to do that on fresh installation, but how to achieve same, when Linux is already installed?
Can i move everything from main partition to secondary (which is encrypted) and somehow change / mount point?

Answer (score 1):

> Can i move everything from main partition to secondary (which is encrypted) and somehow change / mount point?

Yes, you can.

Essentially it is the same process as moving a Linux install to a new disk/partition, only the new partition is encrypted.

See e.g. [How do I move a Linux installation between partitions?](https://superuser.com/questions/22056/how-do-i-move-a-linux-installation-between-partitions)

Only caveat: As the new system needs to boot from an encrypted /, you need an additional, unencrypted /boot so the system can boot. Also, the boot scripts need to support this configuration; current Debian/Ubuntu already does.

*Edit:* BTW, though this should go without saying, make sure you have a working and current backup before doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Unsure if you would be willing to use a third party program to do this but if you are [True Crypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) is available for linux and is pretty good at encrypting the system drive.  I have done so on numerous laptops here at work and use it on a multi boot system at home.  They have just released a new version as well which I believe can spped up the encryption time as well.